# Saved preferences resetting on restart

Tags: macos, preferences

I just bought a MacBook Pro with OS X Lion.

I am having a problem with all my saved preferences: for example, in my Finder "General Preferences", **the new finder window shows** setting keeps resetting each time I turn on my Mac.

I am having the exact same problem with the general system preferences regarding the **restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps** setting; I disabled it but when I restart my laptop, Lion keeps re-opening the programs that were opened in the previous session.

I am a first time Mac user and I am a bit lost with this problem :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the confusion may be in this dialog:

[image: restart dialog]

Unchecking it works for the current restart but the next time it comes up its checked. It has a default state which doesn't seem to have a control in system preferences and may be getting mixed up with this related but different control:

[image: system prefs pane]

No doubt others here will know more about this than I do but I understand how a new user might be confused.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue a few weeks ago.

Launch System Preferences, then select Users and Groups, and select the Login Items tab. The stray window should be in the list of programs. Delete it.

Answer (score -1):

As far as this: "lion keeps re-opening the programs that were opened in the previous session." you seem to not be reading the message.

The preference you are setting is when you close an app and reopen it.

You seem to be closing the machine down and then being surprised the apps that were open when you shut it down re-open.

Read the text you wrote above out loud slowly and I think you may see that one thing is not the same as the other.